# How to initialize a constructor with that takes Strings as parameters?

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I am not sure that I am using the right terminology, but question is how do I properly make a constructor that takes a string in as a parameter?

I am used to having a `const char *` in the constructor instead of strings.

Normally I would do something like this:

```
Name(const char* fName, const char* lName)
    : firstName(0), lastName(0)
{
    char * temp = new char [strlen(fName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(temp, strlen(fName) + 1, fName);
    firstName = temp;

    char * temp2 = new char [strlen(lName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(temp2, strlen(lName) + 1, lName);
    lastName = temp2;
}
```

What if the constructor is this:

```
 Name(const string fName, const string lName) { }
```

Do I still do base member initialization?  do I still need to use string copy in the base of the constructor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and initializer lists:

```
std::string fName, lName;

Name(string fName, string lName):fName(std::move(fName)), lName(std::move(lName))
{
}
```

In this case, you don't need to use terribly bare pointers, you don't need allocate memory, copy characters and finally de-allocate. In addition, this new code has chances to take advantages of moving rather than copying since `std::string` is movable. Also it's useful to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321305/best-form-for-constructors-pass-by-value-or-reference).

And so on....

Comment: Why wouldn't I initialize to 0 as I would with  char *?

Comment: @Sarah: Because std::string objects are not supposed to be 0, because it are objects (not pointers). They are empty, like in the sense of `""`.

Comment: @Sarah: In addition to Martijn's comment, above code is initializing and copying simultaneously. You don't need anything else.

Comment: The above code could actually incur at least 2 copies unless you explicitly specify `std::move` in the initializer list. Also, this is not a good example of move semantics because you still only get 1 copy; exactly the same as if you had used a reference.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Yes, you are right, I don't know why I forgot to use `std::move`

Answer (score 15):

I see that you have already accepted an answer but I would like to expand upon the answers.

As deepmax said, if you pass by value you can write your constructor to take advantage of "move semantics". This means instead of copying data, it can be moved from one variable to another.

Written like so:

```
class Name{
    public:
        Name(std::string var): mem_var(std::move(var)){}

        std::string mem_var;
};
```

Which seems like a good idea, but in reality is no more efficient than the copy constructor

```
class Name{
    public:
        Name(const std::string &var): mem_var(var){}

        std::string mem_var;
};
```

The reason this is, is because in the general use case that looks like this:

```
auto main() -> int{
    Name name("Sample Text");
}
```

only one copy will ever get made either way (see [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)), and in the other case of

```
auto main() -> int{
    std::string myname = "Hugh Jaynus";
    Name name(myname);
}
```

2 copies will be made in the 'efficient' pass-by-value move semantics way!

This is a good example of when the copy constructor (or pass-by-reference) **should** be used, not an example against it.

---

*On the contrary...*

If you write an explicit constructor that makes use of move semantics you could get an efficient solution no matter the circumstance.

Here is how you might write out a name class definition with both constructors:

```
class Name{
    public:
        Name(const std::string &first_, const std::string &last_)
            : first(first_), last(last_){}

        Name(std::string &&first_, std::string &&last_) // rvalue reference
            : first(std::move(first_)), last(std::move(last_)){}

        std::string first, last;
};
```

Then when you use the class the more efficient path should be taken.

If we go back to our examples we can rewrite them to make use of the best or most efficient constructor:

```
int main(){
    // pass by reference best here
    Name myname("Yolo", "Swaggins");

    // move most efficient here
    // but never use 'first' and 'last' again or UB!
    std::string first = "Hugh", last = "Jaynus";
    Name yourname(std::move(first), std::move(last));
}
```

Never just take for granted that one solution is better than all others!

Comment: I see what you did there 

Comment: Where are two copies in case of pass-by-value constructor and
```
auto main() -> int{
    std::string myname = "Hugh Jaynus";
    Name name(myname);
}
```?

One copy is from `myname` variable to constructor argument, which is then moved to the class member.

Also consider this article which explains the topic better than I could do in a comment: http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2012/03/rvalue-references-in-constructor-when.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm used to do this:

```
std::string fName;
std::string lName;

Name(const std::string &fName, const std::string &lName) :
     fName(fName), lName(lName)
{
}
```

Using the references saves the work of copying the strings to a new object on the stack, it will just pass the reference to the existing string. Once you are assigning them to the class members, they will get copied.

Comment: Why you don't pass them by value if you concern efficiency?

Comment: but what if I'm not using references to strings in my parameters?

Comment: @MM: I wrote that in my answer: because they won't get copied by passing them to the constructor. The constructor will have to copy them as well, in every case (with or without references).

Comment: @Sarah: Well, then you either stick with your current situation or change it to const references.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Move semantics (C++11) say something else, read [this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: @MM.: I read the article, and if I understood correctly, it only gives performance gains in specific situation. This case does not apply, I think? The final copy from the method argument to the class member can never be avoided right? When using references, and doing this: `new Name(getSomeString(), getSomeString())`, we would have two copies per argument: 1) from getSomeString() to the callee, 2) from the callee to the class member. If we did the same, using pass by value, we would only have one copy: from getSomeString() to the class member. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: If you pass by value, in case of temporary passed objects (e.g. `Name name("Martijn","Courteaux");`) it will _move_ the values and you have no copy. In case of non-temporary passed objects (e.g. `Name name(fn, ln);`) you have one copy as same as passing by reference. Summery: Passing by value can avoid unnecessary copies for temp objects. Therefore, it's logical to prefer it.

Comment: I understand that. But that seems logical to me, because the create `Name name` object is on the stack, so the compiler can just put it immediately at the right position. But I was talking about a `new`-ly created object (on the heap).

Comment: So, to ask in a clear way: When create a `new Name("Martijn", "Courteaux");` (`new`, so on the heap). It wouldn't make any difference if we did pass by value or by reference, right? It would have to copy both times once?

Comment: It doesn't depend on `Name` is on stack or heap. Pass by value has the chance to move those names to class members instead of copying.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep const char * as your constructor input types do this.

```
std::string fName;
std::string lName;

Name(const char *_fName, const char *_lName) :
     fName(_fName), lName(_lName)
{
}
```

You can construct a std::string from a const char.

Comment: Identifiers starting with a leading underscore are reserved by the compiler, you should have them trailing.